# jquery click function dont work on every input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my page I can create a new div container with 2 field (1x input type text, 1x textarea), when I press on the button *"Schritt hinzufügen"*. 
If I press the button *"Schritt entfernen"*, it will remove the last container. I use jquery for this action. If I press on the button *"Erstellen"*, jquery will check if all fields are filled (without the input fields type file). If some fields arent filled, they will get a red border.

But now I want, that when I **focus** a input field, that the red edge will go away. It works not 100%. On this code it work's (not created with jquery):

```html
            <div class="step">
                <div class="header_step">Allgemeines zum Tutorial</div>
                <div class="body_step">
                    <a class="create_tutorial_a">Titel des Tutorial's</a><input class="create_tutorial_input" type="text" name="input_tutorialtitle_name"/>
                    <br>
                    <a class="create_tutorial_a">Autor des Tutorial's</a><input class="create_tutorial_input" type="text" name="input_tutorialauthor_name"/>
                    <br><br>
                    <a class="create_tutorial_a_full_width">Beschreibung des Tutorial's</a>
                    <br>
                    <textarea class="create_tutorial_textarea" name="input_tutorialdescription_name"></textarea>
                </div>
</div>
```

And here is a exapmple div container (created with jquery):

```html
<div class="step">
  <div class="header_step">Schritt 1 des Tutorial's</div>
  <div class="body_step">
    <a class="create_tutorial_a">Titel des Schrittes</a>
    <input name="input_title_name1" class="create_tutorial_input" type="text">
    <br>
    <a class="create_tutorial_a">Bild</a>
    <input type="file">
    <br><br>
    <a class="create_tutorial_a_full_width">Beschreibung des Schrittes</a>
    <br>
    <textarea class="create_tutorial_textarea" name="input_description_name1">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

if I press again the button *"Schritt hinzufügen*", I will get the same container, only the **name's** of the fields, will get a other number.

And here is the jquery code to remove a class of the input field's:

```
$('input[type="text"]').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
});

$('textarea').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
});
```

If you didnt understand me, you can test it by yourself. Here is the page link: [MyPage](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Design_3.0/index.php?content=create_tutorial)

First press the button *"Schritt hinzufügen"* two times, then press the button *"Erstellen*". After this, every input field (not filled) will get a red border. If you focus the first input field of the page (*"Titel des Tutorial's"*) and then "unfocus" it, you will see the border will go away. But at the created step's with jquery it wont work (focus them & unfocus then (the border wont go away)). Maybe someone of you have a idea^^

Edit --- My complete js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 11; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".all_steps"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $("#add_step"); //Add button ID
    var remove_step     = $("#remove_step");
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(){ //on add input button click
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="step"><div class="header_step">Schritt '+ x +' des Tutorial\'s</div><div class="body_step"><a class="create_tutorial_a">Titel des Schrittes</a><input name="input_title_name'+x+'" class="create_tutorial_input" type="text" /><br><a class="create_tutorial_a">Bild</a><input type="file" /><br><br><a class="create_tutorial_a_full_width">Beschreibung des Schrittes</a><br><textarea class="create_tutorial_textarea" name="input_description_name'+x+'"></textarea></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
    });
   
        
    $(remove_step).click(function(){ //user click on remove text
        if(x > 1){
            $('.all_steps .step:last').remove();
            x--;
        }
    });
        
    $('form.send').on('submit', function(){

        var empty = false;
        
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                $(this).addClass("empty_field");
                empty = true;
            }
            else{
                $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
            }
        });

        $('textarea').each(function(){
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                $(this).addClass("empty_field");
                empty = true;
            }
            else{
                $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
            }
        });


        if(empty == false){
            var that = $(this),
                url = that.attr('action'),
                type = that.attr('method'),
                data = {};
            
            that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
                var that = $(this),
                    name = that.attr('name'),
                    value = that.val();
                
                data[name] = value;
            });
            
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: type,
                data: data,
                success: function(response){
                    window.location.replace("index.php?content=create_tutorial_successful");
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log("Alles ausfüllen");
        }

        return false;
    });

    
    $('input[type="text"]').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
    });

    $('textarea').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Friendly FYI, since you already define `add_button` and `remove_step` as jQuery elements, you don't need to additionally wrap them in bling when attaching a click handler. I'm not sure whether there are any performance implications (or if jQuery is smart enough to not create _another_ jQuery object). Anyway, the following would suffice :)
`var add_button = $('#add_step'); add_button.click(function() { ... });`

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint! I didnt saw your comment sorry! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the function where you create new elements to be completely certain, but from what I see, I think you need to reapply your click listeners when you create your new elements. They're not "retroactive", meaning the "click" you add will target what's in the dom at the moment you set them, but not new elements you create afterwards.

I tried on your page through console to set the click events with the exact code you have, and it works. 
So when creating new element you can probably use something like:

```
$(your_new_element).click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
});
```

on each element you create for which you want this behavior.

EDIT:

Something like this:

```
 $(add_button).click(function(){ //on add input button click
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="step"><div class="header_step">Schritt '+ x +' des Tutorial\'s</div><div class="body_step"><a class="create_tutorial_a">Titel des Schrittes</a><input name="input_title_name'+x+'" class="create_tutorial_input" type="text" /><br><a class="create_tutorial_a">Bild</a><input type="file" /><br><br><a class="create_tutorial_a_full_width">Beschreibung des Schrittes</a><br><textarea class="create_tutorial_textarea" name="input_description_name'+x+'"></textarea></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
    add_click_events();
    });

function add_click_events(){
 $('input[type="text"]').last().click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
    });

    $('textarea').last().click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
    });
}
```

And add add_click_events() at first launch also.

Comment: @Julien Instead of redefining the click handler every time new elements are created, why not just use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead?

Comment: @Sean3z I think you're right, it would be cleaner and more efficient.